QR algorithm, equivalence of r shifts and r times 1 shift
Is it true that in general the general $QR$ algorithm applied to
$A$, a multiple shift of degree $r$ is equivalent to a sequence of $r$ single shifts of degree $1$? (Assuming that no shift is an exact eigenvalue of $A$). (Equivalent in the sense that the computed matrices  equivalent in the sense that the computed matrices $A_k$ coincide up to diagonal, unitary simliarity transformations.
How can I show that?
